# React context isn't found within it's own file changing from JS to TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I had my file of a context and context provider which worked just fine. I'm doing a shift and changing all files to TypeScript, so wanted to change this file too. But I'm having a weird probem I can't quite figure out.

I get an error warning from VS that `Cannot find namespace 'gameInfoContext'` . It's literally right there, not sure what I am doing wrong here.

This is my code (trimmed it down for clarity, the issue is still there like this too:

```
import React, { ReactNode } from "react";

type Props = {
  children: ReactNode;
};

interface ContextValues {
  [key: string]: any;
}

export const gameInfoContext = React.createContext<ContextValues | undefined>(
  undefined
);

export const GameInfoProvider = ({ children }: Props) => {

 return (
    <gameInfoContext.Provider>
      {children}
    </gameInfoContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My file extension was `ts` rather then `tsx`.